# Dúvida sobre Wordpress

Tags: php, html, wordpress

Estou precisando de um sistema de notícias para um site ja pronto. Só que eu não conheço muito de wordpress, não sei se é possível instalar o wordpress em um site já pronto. Queria saber se é possível, pois lá tem um sistema de noticias completo.

Comment: Sim é possível, mas se tem de ter um mínimo de conhecimento na plataforma que está utilizando (no caso o WP), da forma que está sua questão é ampla, então considere fazer um [tour] e visitar a [help], para obter melhores resultados. Boa sorte.

Comment: No caso você teria que migrar seu site pronto para o WP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Olá! É possível sim!

Mas se você é iniciante, tente comprar algum tema e manipular para ganhar o seu trocado. Eu comecei assim, e fui ganhando tempo até aprender a dominar os princípais recursos do Wordpress por debaixo dos panos.

Existe diversos tutoriais na internet, caso você não tenha pressa por aprender, meu conselho é assistir essa série vídeos: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h1JmDwJZu3Q

Neste canal tem muita coisa boa. Mas por favor, siga o seguinte roteiro de estudo:

1. Aprenda a usar o Wordpress e conheça seus princípais recursos
2. Aprenda Lógica de programação! Aqui não importa a lingaugem que vai iniciar, mas eu recomendo começar pela linguagem C, pois diversas linguagens são baseadas nela, assim como PHP, Java, entre outros. [Acesse este link!](http://binariux.com.br/category/desenvolvimento/linguagem-c/)
3. Aprenda PHP! Para aprender Wordpress por debaixo dos panos, precisa ser um programador intermediário na linguagem. Eu comecei a escrever uma sequência de aulas sobre o assunto. [Por acessar clicando aqui!](http://binariux.com.br/php-definicao-e-historia-da-linguagem/)
   Mas caso você tem um dinheiro para investir em curso, cara... sem dúvida alguma! [EU SUPER RECOMENDO ESTE CURSO: PHP do Zero ao Profissional!](https://go.hotmart.com/S5869886E) Lá, ele também fala sobre a ferramenta do Wordpress. Super recomendo MESMO! Com este curso qualquer pessoa pode aprender a programar e ganhar dinheiro com isso!
4. Partiu Wordpress! Aquele link do Youtube que passei para você...lá em cima! Pois é! ... Agora é hora de partir para ele e aprender a montar seu tema em Wordpress.

Espero ter ajudado você e também a outras pessoas que tenham essa mesma dúvida!

Comment: Muito obrigado! Você é o cara!

Comment: Disponha! Não sou o cara.. rsrs
Ainda tenho muito o que aprender!
Não se esqueã de marcar sua pergunta como **resolvido**.